# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election

Travel's [third moderator election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: JoErNanO] [image: JonathanReez]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive) for their contributions as they are stepping down. I expect they will still be around to help lead the site from a less formal, but no less important, position.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.com/results/5055933453434880/0).

Answer (score 12):

Well done Joe and Jonathan - congratulations. Enjoy your slightly increased powers :-)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks everyone for the support. Now, I was promised a Travel Emperor crown, which I can't seem to find that anywhere in the mod tools. What's that all about?

In all seriousness, I am ready to do my best to upkeep this community. Feel free to [ping me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)  should you need any help.

Thank you @mindcorrosive for the good work done so far. See you around!

Comment: The emperor has no headgear!

Comment: @JonEricson Well that explains it then. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, we snuck yours as a spare on a night out.  It's a little worse for wear ;)

Comment: I believe StackExchange will send us a "Travel Emperor" T-shirt. Close enough I guess :)

Comment: @JoErNanO  Congrats dude!

Comment: I am sorry for being late (it took time to get it up the mountain) ....  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtme3.png

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Awesome!